# pyspark string matching - pick first match

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, string-matching

I have two tables.

comment_df

```
| Date | Comment | 
|:---- |:------:| 
| 20/01/2020 | Transfer from Euro Account to HSBC account done on Monday but AMEX payment was on Tue. |
| 20/01/2020 | Brian initiated a Transfer from Euro Account to Natwest last Tuesday. |
| 21/01/2020 | AMEX payment to Natwest was delayed for second time in a row. |
| 21/01/2020 | AMEX receipts from Euro Account delayed. |
```

code_df

```
| Tag | Comment | 
|:---- |:------:| 
| EURO | Euro Account to HSBC |
| Natwest | Euro Account to Natwest |
| AMEX | AMEX payment |
```

The desired table

```
| Date | Comment | Tag |
|:---- |:------:| ----:|
| 20/01/2020 | Transfer from Euro Account to HSBC account done on Monday but AMEX payment was on Tue.| EURO |
| 20/01/2020 | Brian initiated a Transfer from Euro Account to Natwest last Tuesday. | Natwest |
| 21/01/2020 | AMEX payment to Natwest was delayed for second time in a row. | AMEX | 
| 21/01/2020 | AMEX receipts from Euro Account delayed. | |
```

So the first comment has two tags (Euro Account to HSBC & AMEX payment) but I want the result to show the first tag it comes across and not duplicate the rows.  Below is what was previously suggested.

```
code_df = code_df.withColumnRenamed('Comment', 'Commentcode')

result = comment_df.join(code_df, comment_df.Comment.contains(code_df.Commentcode), 'left').drop('Commentcode')

result.show(truncate=False)

+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|Date      |Comment                                                              |Tag    |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|20/01/2020|Transfer from Euro Account to HSBC account done on Monday but AMEX payment was on Tue. |EURO|
|20/01/2020|Brian initiated a Transfer from Euro Account to Natwest last Tuesday.|Natwest|
|21/01/2020|AMEX payment to Natwest was delayed for second time in a row.        |AMEX|
|21/01/2020|AMEX receipts from Euro Account delayed.                             |null|
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: could you also mention the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can order the results based on the position of the matched string, and only get the first match by filtering the position.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = comment_df.join(
    code_df,
    comment_df.Comment.contains(code_df.Commentcode),
    'left'
).withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy('Date', 'Comment')
              .orderBy(F.expr('instr(Comment, Commentcode)'))
    )
).filter('rn = 1')
```